# VBA Lotus Notes parsing a response to a pop up message?

Tags: excel, vba, email, lotus-notes

I have code that attaches a file and a body to a new email and sends it and then closes the email. The issue is, I get a HCI pop up box saying 'Do you want to save this new document?' when the sent email is closed. I have been trying to find some info about this but I haven't been able to find anything regarding parsing an answer to select 'No' on the pop up box?

Any links or guidance would be greatly appreciated, I have included my sending code for context.

```
Public Sub LN_Send_Email()

    Const EMBED_ATTACHMENT As Long = 1454

    Dim Notes As Object
    Dim Workspace As Object
    Dim UIdoc As Object
    Dim Attachment As Object
    Dim Data As String
    Dim attachmentFile As String
    Dim File As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Recipient As String
    Dim Doc As Object
    
    Row = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To Row
    
    Recipient = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
    
    If Recipient <> "" Then
    
    
    File = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    
    attachmentFile = "Directory\" & File
    
    Data = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    
    Set Notes = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set Workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
    Workspace.ComposeDocument , , "Memo"
    
    Set UIdoc = Workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set Doc = UIdoc.Document
   
    With UIdoc
        .FieldSetText "EnterSendTo", Recipient
        .FieldSetText "Subject", "Subject " & Data
        .GotoField "Body"
        .Import "HTML File", "Directory"
    
        If attachmentFile <> "" Then
            If Dir(attachmentFile) <> "" Then
                Set Attachment = .Document.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment")
                .InsertText String(2, vbLf) & "File attached: " & Mid(attachmentFile, InStrRev(attachmentFile, "\") + 1)
                Attachment.EmbedObject EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", attachmentFile
            Else
                MsgBox "File " & attachmentFile & " not found, so not attached to email."
            End If
        End If
        
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Send
        .Close
        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        
    End With
    
    Set UIdoc = Nothing
    Set Workspace = Nothing
    Set Notes = Nothing
    
    End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting

```
doc.SaveOptions = "0"
```

before you send the document.  This flag tells the client to not prompt to save the mail document.

If this doesn't work, you may need to use the doc (NotesDocument class)  rather than the UIDoc (NotesUIDocument class) to create and send the mail.

Comment: Thats frustrating  because I tried .SaveOptions = 0 before and it didin't work but now "0" seems to work even though it doesn't say anywhere that it should work for UIDocument class...